# Java Thread that does not have a loop in the run method

Tags: java, multithreading

If a Java thread does not have a loop in its run method, is it safe to assume that the Thread would be destroyed once the run method has completed. Let's consider the following code,

```
Thread t = new Thread(){
   public void run(){
      System.out.print("Hello World!");
   }
};

t.start();
```

In the above example, once the run method ends, how do I return the system-resources back to the system?

Comment: what do you mean with system-resources?

Comment: When your program exits the `main()` method, how do you ensure the system resources (Memory and CPU) are returned back ?

Answer (score 7):

> Is it safe to assume that the Thread would be destroyed once the run
>   method has completed.

Yes.

> How do I return the system-resources back to the system?

Object References(i.e. Memory resources) will be garbage collected. No specific action needs to be taken.

File, DB resources can be closed in the `finally` block after you are done using them.

```
finally {
 resource.close();
}
```

You can also use the new [try with resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) in Java 7

Comment: Perfect answer to the question (+1)

Answer (score 1):

All system resources related to given object are freed by the garbage collector as it sees fit.

While the resources indeed will be returned, it is very important to not rely on them being returned immediately or even in a limited time; never rely on a garbage collector doing something when you want it. It was that way with scoped objects in C++ but it's not so in java.

Some resources may be freed manually (usually a `obj.close()` method), like files and sockets.